# Understanding loops within loops C++

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, while-loop

Apologies for the newbie question but I'm new to programming and learning C++. I'm working my way through C++ Primer and I've gotten to the If statement section where this code has been written.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{ 
    // currVal is the number we're counting, new values will be put into val
    int currVal = 0, val = 0;
    // Read first number and check there is data to process
    if (std::cin >> currVal) {
        int cnt = 1; // Store the count for the current value we're processing
        while (std::cin >> val) { // read the remaining numbers
            if (val == currVal)   // if the values are the same
                ++cnt;            // add 1 to count (cnt)
            else {  // Otherwise, print the count for the previous value
                std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times\n";
                    currVal = val; // remember the new value
                    cnt = 1;       // reset the counter
            }
        } // while loop ends here
          // rememeber to print the count for the last value in the flile
        std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times.\n";


    } // Outermost if statement ends here
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled the logic is incorrect. For example, when I enter 51 25 14 51 51 51 25. I get the following:

51 occurs 1 times
25 occurs 1 times
14 occurs 1 times
51 occurs 3 times

I've tried breaking down the code but with loops within loops it's making my head spin.

Again, apologies for the noob question but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is there something you don't understand, or are you asking how to get the count for "51" to be correct?

Comment: I see only one loop.

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. With a debugger you can step through the program line by line and watch what it does as it does it.

Comment: to break the loop `while (std::cin >> val)` the only way is to reach EOF or to enter something else than an integer, so after `51 25 14 51 51 51 25` enter `a` or anything not being an integer, or the EOF depending on the OS you use

Comment: Sidenote: You don't store the numbers already entered anywhere so you'll have to enter all 51's, then all 25's etc. for this show the total number of 51's entered etc.

Comment: Now, hit `CTRL-D` or `CTRL-Z` (whichever one is appropriate for your operating system), to send EOF to the program, or have the program read its input from a file, and see what happens. You'll be surprised.

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually want to achieve. If just counting arbitrary numbers, you might use a `std::map` instead and just upcount the respecive values: `++map[val]`. Be aware that `operator[]` for maps will insert a new (default) element if the element is not yet there...

Comment: The loop, as written, counts _consecutive_ occurrences of integers, not total occurrences. Every time it sees a new number it starts over.

Comment: The point of the exercise might be counting consecutive occurrences of a value, like run length encoding.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. This question was a case of me looking at the exercise in the wrong way, not the code. Apologies!

Comment: @j4yman If you question has been answered please edit it with the answer.... and say it has been answered...

Comment: @YunfeiChen Sorry, that's wrong processing here on SO. One does **not** edit the answer into the question, one writes an answer to his own question and accepts it – and *yes*, answering his own question is totally fine ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
 if (std::cin >> currVal) {
        int cnt = 1; // Store the count for the current value we're processing
        while (std::cin >> val) { // read the remaining numbers
            if (val == currVal)   // if the values are the same
                ++cnt;            // add 1 to count (cnt)
            else {  // Otherwise, print the count for the previous value
                std::cout << currVal << " occurs " << cnt << " times\n";
                    currVal = val; // remember the new value
                    cnt = 1;       // reset the counter
            }
        }
```

It says cin >> currval, which basically means if you are entering a value do the following. It goes through the first time, and then you go in your while loop which basically says while you still have input, if the val == currVal increase cnt, otherwise do the thing in the else block. you have 7 input so the loop goes through 7 times, what is so confusing about that??